# Не отображается Content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Можете подсказать в чем проблема. У меня есть UserControl c ListBox, с помощью него я выбираю страницу для отображения в ContentPresenter.
В DataTemplate DataType кидаю ViewModel. Например:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:DashboardViewModel}">
    <Views:Dashboard/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Во Views Dashboard прописываю DataContext. В ContentPresenter прописываю:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentContent, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Прописываю

```
MenuItem = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel>()
{
    new MenuItemModel("Текст", "Текст", new DashboardViewModel())
};
```

но почему то не отображается Views Dashboard(Xaml).

UserControl:

```
<ListBox Style="{DynamicResource CustomListBox}" 
         ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CustomListBoxItem}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=ItemsSource}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=SelectedItem}"> 
</ListBox>
```

UserControl.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable),
        typeof(NavigationMenu), new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object),
        typeof(NavigationMenu), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

public IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
}

public object SelectedItem
{
    get => GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
    set => SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
}
```

Models: MenuItemModel

```
public string Icon { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public BaseViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

public MenuItemModel(string icon, string name, BaseViewModel viewModel)
{
    Icon = icon;
    Name = name;
    ViewModel = viewModel;
}
```

WindowViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel> MenuItem { get; set; }
public BaseViewModel currentContent;
public MenuItemModel selectedMenu;

public BaseViewModel CurrentContent
{
    get => currentContent;
    set
    {
        currentContent = value;
        OnPropertyChanget(CurrentContent.ToString());
    }
}

public MenuItemModel SelectedMenu
{
    get => selectedMenu;
    set
    {
        selectedMenu = value;
        CurrentContent = value.ViewModel;
    }
}

MenuItem = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel>()
{
    new MenuItemModel("Текст", "Текст", new DashboardViewModel())
};
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:DashboardViewModel}">
        <Views:Dashboard/>
    </DataTemplate></Window.Resource>

<CustomControls:NavigationMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItem}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenu, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentContent, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Приведите пример для воспроизведения проблемы, чтобы можно было вставить в студию и запустить, потому что сейчас недостаточно деталей.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Подправил основной текст.

Comment: UserControl: `ListBox ... SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=SelectedItem}"` — вот здесь добавьте `Mode=TwoWay`

Comment: Воу-воу, `OnPropertyChanget(CurrentContent.ToString());` — это что такое? Замените на `OnPropertyChanget(nameof(CurrentContent));`

Comment: Добавил ModeToWay ничего не изменилось. В другой программе которую делал OnPropertyChanget(CurrentContent.ToString()) все работало

Comment: Во @АндрейNOP изменил на OnPropertyChanget(nameof(CurrentContent)); все заработало. Спасибо большое.

Comment: *В другой программе которую делал OnPropertyChanget(CurrentContent.ToString()) все работало* — значит вам сильно повезло